# How do I disable the enabled feature when I enable a new feature in togglz?

Tags: togglz

Say I have features `A`, `B`, `C`, and `A` is enabled by default. `B` and `C` disabled.

When I enable `B` I want to disable `A`: only one feature should be enabled at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to implement a custom version of the `StateRepository` interface. Information on this can be found [on the togglz documentation](http://www.togglz.org/documentation/repositories.html)

Next override the `setFeatureState(...)` function for the required functionality.

- Disable active features (query via FeatureManager or Feature enum - you may need to implement custom versions of these classes for the desired functionality)
- Enable the feature being set.